# JPA Hibernate Many To One. Delete One

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have one reletionship many to one.
Many cars have one owner. How delete the owner only if all of his cars deleted?

Ex one owner have two cars.
1)delete first car nothing happens to owner. delete second car delete owner.(Can be achieved with orphanremoval=true?)
2) delete owner delete all his car. (Can be achieved with CascadeType.Remove ?)

```
class Car{

@ManyToOne(orphanremoval=true)
private Owner owner;
}

class Owner{

@OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.REMOVE)
private List<Car> cars;
}
```

Comment: Orphan removal should work. Haven't you tried it?

Comment: I am wondering if a good design approach

Comment: `@ManyToOne` does not have the `orphanRemoval` attribute ([ref](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html)) - if it had I don't see why it would be a bad approach. In this case, you probably have no other option than to do what you want in code. Watch out for concurrency issues (example: owner has 2 remaining cars, 2 concurrent requests arrive to remove each of them; if naively implemented, each concurrent transaction counts remaining cars as 1, so does not remove the owner!!!)

Comment: thank you for your reply. so in first example with car and private owner should I use instead of orphanremoval CascadeType.Remove. So in db I will have 
    car1=> ownerA
car2=> ownerA. with cascadetype.remove. if car 1deleted ownerA will be deleted also. Is it cause problem in second row?( car2=>ownerA).

Comment: I still dont understand how delete owner only if delete both 2 cars.